# net view showing disconnected computer

Tags: windows-xp, home-networking

I'm working on a simple network, 2 computers (both Win XP), and a 2-Wire router.  I've physically disconnected one of the computers, but it still shows up in the list when I run Net View on the other computer.  I've searched this, and other forums, for an answer, but so far haven't come across this scenario.  I admit to being a newbie re the Net commands, so possibly I'm misunderstanding something - I thought Net View only listed the currently connected devices, but it seems to be remembering the previous connection.

Comment: Forgot to mention - if I Log Off/On, or restart my computer, the Net View list shows correctly.

Comment: does the command `nbtstat -R` clear it up for you?

Comment: @Frank - No, that doesn't seem to do it either.  I left the one computer off overnight, and brought the other one out of hibernation this morning.  Net View still shows the disconnected computer.  Thanks for the suggestion.